# Is there a faster alternative to kramdown that still uses PHP Markdown syntax?

Tags: ruby, performance, markdown, jekyll

I just moved my site to Octopress, which comes preconfigured with the rdiscount Markdown parser, but my archives have a lot of posts that were written with the [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) syntax. The main syntax I need is for footnotes:

```
This is my sentence.[^1]

[^1]: This is my footnote.
```

Kramdown does it, but it's slowing down site generation. As far as I understand rediscount is by far the fastest parser, but it doesn't handle this footnote syntax. Are there others that are faster *and* have this syntax built in? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Octopress uses [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), which has 3 markdown parameters:

- rdiscount
- kramdown
- maruku

It seems that you have tried the first two, but not the third. I've given a look at [its specs](https://github.com/nex3/maruku/blob/master/spec/block_docs/footnotes.md) and it seems to support footnotes. I don't know whether it's faster or slower than rdiscount, though.

Best option is to try it. If it works, then that's your option. If not, then there is no other alternative.